# match the number with randomly generated number and display how many digits matched

Tags: javascript, math, numbers

Suppose I have a number Ex:895678 that randomly got generated and I made a guess from input and I need to match my guess(5678) with previous random number and should say how many digits are matched(4) through coding can you help me with this.

Comment: _SO_ is not a free coding service. Do add your efforts in your question so that contributors can help you solve your problem. Kindly read [__How do I ask a good question?__](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I just got the answer Rayon, Could you please help me to see if this is the efficient one?

Comment: Bhargav, Have a look - https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity

Answer (score 0):

```
const randomNum =  870308;
const gussedNum =  870306;

I have converted both of these numbers into arrays and looped over them

let matched = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < gussedNumArray.length; i++) {
      if (rndNumArray[i] === gussedNumArray[i]){
        matched += 1;
  }
}
```

This gave me the correct answer.